# Importing a submodule of a custom package using the dot notation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I'm guessing this may already be answered, but all my searches are turning up other import issues. Then again, perhaps I just don't know the proper terms to search for.

If I create a package with a module, it seems I can use `from mypackage import mymodule` to use `mymodule` in my code. However, I can't use `import mypackage` and then use `mypackage.mymodule`. With this I get a `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mymodule'` error. Why is this and how do I set it up so I can use this?

My package structure is shown below. All the `__init__.py`s are empty.

```
myproject
  __init__.py
  mypackage
    __init__.py
    mymodule.py
  mymain.py # Doing the importing.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Submodules are not implicitly imported. You will need to import `.mymodule` in `mypackage/__init__.py` unless you explicitly want to import `mypackage.mymodule`.