# Make all modules of a package available via dot notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, package

I found this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011200/importing-a-submodule-of-a-custom-package-using-the-dot-notation) explaining that for a module to be available on the package, it needs to be imported in the `__init__.py` file of that package.

I was wondering if there's a way to make all modules in a package available via the init, without explicitly importing each one?

i.e. if this was my project structure

```
mypackage
  __init__.py
  mymodule.py
  mymodule2.py
```

and I want to be able to access the modules like so

```
import mypackage

mypackage.mymodule.foo()
mypackage.mymodule2.bar()
```

In `mypackage/__init__.py`, I want to be able to import all modules in the directory, so something like this

```
from . import *
```

Currently, the only way I can get this to work, is having this in `mypackage/__init__.py`

```
from . import mymodule
from . import mymodule2
```

Apologies if this question has already been asked, I couldn't seem to find any information in regards to this, perhaps I was using the wrong terminology!

Thanks.

Comment: instead of `import mypackage` why can't you do `from mypackage import *` and then just `mymodule.foo()` ?

Comment: @Daniel because that is against all best practices in the book (at least without defining `__all__` in `__init__.py`)

Comment: @DeepSpace ofcourse, it's not best practice, but it does exactly what he wants. all modules in certain package would be imported.

Comment: @Daniel because the module and class names lose their meaning if imported alone and I want to avoid smurf naming